# How to Resolve FirebasInitProvide Issue in an Android Project..?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin

I have added firebase into my project. I am using some of its libraries including firebase dom, Crashlaytics and library for notification Puropes.When i clone the project from the first time in which i am facing issue it run Successfully afterwards it statrted to throwing error

Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f110069

Any body know? why it is giving this resource error and how to resolve it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: code is not necessary for this Question i have provided more than enogh information